# append json output before saving into file

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I am trying to curl some URL which returns a json file, as follows

```
[
  10,
  20,
  30,
  40,
]
```

now I am trying to save these value in file with a variable assigned to it.

need output in file as

```
a=10
b=20
c=30
d=40
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `implode` to create the letters by array index, which is provided in `.key` when `to_entries` is applied to an array.

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\([.key + 97] | implode)=\(.value)"'
```

```
a=10
b=20
c=30
d=40
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/kTFXBy5YZrG)

---

To provide individual names, you can introduce an array of names and use `transpose` to make the alignment:

```bash
jq -r '
  [["Price", "Amount", "Value", "Tax"], .]
  | transpose[] | "\(first)=\(last)"
'
```

```
Price=10
Amount=20
Value=30
Tax=40
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NWOd2XMdH1v)

Note: The list could also be provided from outside jq:

- using a JSON array

```bash
jq -r --argjson names '["Price", "Amount", "Value", "Tax"]' \
  '[$names, .] | transpose[] | "\(first)=\(last)"'
```

- using positional parameters

```bash
jq -r '[$ARGS.positional, .] | transpose[] | "\(first)=\(last)"' \
  --args Price Amount Value Tax
```

Comment: thanks for help, how can I replace variable name from alphabets to some meaningful variable names? for eg Price=10 instead of a=10

Comment: @nis I have added an alternative to provide individual names.